# CORS doesn't work when fetching POST request to api from React client

Tags: reactjs, post, cors, fetch, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using asp.net core 2.1 and I have register method in controller for user registration. In my client code I'm using fetch as following:

```
`fetch ('http://localhost:53531/api/account/register', {          
            method: 'POST',        
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},   
            body: JSON.stringify(values)
         })`
```

for posting my form data.
and methods in my Startup.cs look like this:

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddCors();
```

Configure:

```
 app.UseCors( builder => 
                 { builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/")
    .AllowAnyOrigin() 
    .AllowCredentials() 
    .AllowAnyMethod() 
    .AllowAnyHeader(); });
```

Despite everything I'm getting this error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:53531/api/account/register' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are developing locally, add this line in your package.json:

   ```
   "proxy": "http://localhost:53531
   ```
2. Change your fetch url into:

   ```
   fetch ('/api/account/register', {          
       method: 'POST',        
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},   
       body: JSON.stringify(values)
   })
   ```

Comment: I tried so and i get this : POST http://localhost:3000/api/account/register 404 (Not Found) ..Not sure what I'm missing here :/

Comment: SInce it's not CORS error anymore, please make sure that this path : 'api/account/register' exists.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `AllowAnyOrigin()` if you have use `AllowCredentials()` already.Besides, from the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-the-allowed-origins):

> Specifying AllowAnyOrigin and AllowCredentials is an insecure configuration and can result in cross-site request forgery. The CORS service returns an invalid CORS response when an app is configured with both methods.

Try:

```
app.UseCors( builder => 
{ 
      builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/")   
              .AllowCredentials() 
              .AllowAnyMethod() 
              .AllowAnyHeader(); 
});
```